# remove newline followed by multiple tabs regex

Tags: regex, sed, regexp-replace

I tried to remove newline followed by tab with space using following regex in sed

```
sed "s|\n[\t|\s]*| |" input.log  > output.log
```

It does not work but if I use per then it replaces all new line as well. I want to replace only newline followed by tab or space multiple times (more than 1 time) with a space.

```
perl -pe '/\n[\t|\s]*/ /' input.log  > output.log
```

Sample data in below link:

https://regex101.com/r/D9sHjG/1

I want to remove blue highlighted tabs after newline.
[image]

Comment: Thanks for showing your efforts, could you please post samples of input and expected output in your question to make it more clear and we can test our code also on those samples, thank you.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13, thanks. I have added picture where I want to remove new lines in mysql logs.

Comment: You probably  just need `perl -pe 's/^\h+/ /' input.log  > output.log`

Comment: Looks like you need: `sed -E '2,$s/^[[:blank:]]+//' file > output`

Answer (score 4):

***1st solution:*** In `sed` you can try following code. Using GNU `sed`'s `-E` option to enable ERE(extended regular expression) along with its `-z` option to read whole Input_file at once. Then in main program using `s` option of `sed` to perform substitution; where substituting newline followed by tabs/spaces and substituting it with only new lines as per required output.

```bash
sed -E -z 's~\n[[:blank:]]+~\n~g'  Input_file
```

---

---

***2nd solution:*** In GNU `awk` with setting `RS` to null will also help here to do the substitution, like as follows:

```bash
awk -v RS= '{gsub(/\n[[:blank:]]+/,"\n")} {ORS=RT;print}' Input_file
```

Comment: can you please explain how awk and sed part is working?

Comment: @kinkajou, using `-E` option to enable ERE(for regex) and then `-z` option is for reading file in a single shot so that we can read new lines there. Then doing substitution part to substitute new line followed by TAB OR Space(s) (`[[:blank:]]` is the way to match both together in regex) with only new lines. using `g` means do it Globally for all possible matches. Let me know if this helps you. **for `awk`**: Also its more or less same concept only. There also reading file in paragraph mode and then performing substitution same as sed and printing the line.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to match more than 1 tabs/spaces, you can use a quantifier for 2 or more spaces and replace that match with a space.

```
sed 's/^[[:space:]]\{2,\}/ /' file
```

If you want to skip the first line, you can specify a range from the second line till the end:

```
sed '2,$s/^[[:space:]]\{2,\}/ /' file
```

Or if it is the first line, don't do the replacement:

```
sed '1!s/^[[:space:]]\{2,\}/ /' file
```